# I cant install scipy

Tags: python, installation, scipy

All of my python code just stopped working.  I have narrowed it down to scipy.  I removed it and tried to reinstall but it keeps failing.  See the figure below.  I am running Python 3.11.4, and the latest version of numpy.  Any help would be much appreciated!

[shell window showing failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV4BQ.png)

Comment: The official installation instructions say to use `python -m pip install scipy`.  I honestly don't know if that's effectively any different from the command you used.  But I would give it a shot.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

After I looked at your error I think the error is that you don't have a c compiler in your environment according to this line:

[image: error dicription]

So, to fix this you can install the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ or the MinGW Compiler: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/.

Comment: THank you.  I have the intel versions installed.  I do not know why they were not being read.  They were in the path.  In any case, I installed the MinGW compiler and that worked!

Comment: so if it's worked mark the answer as right so others can benefit from the question and the answer.